# What's going on with my boolean difference Modifier?

Tags: modifiers, extrude

[image: Pic 1]

[Instructable](https://www.instructables.com/id/3D-Printed-Speaker-Enclosures-With-Lights/)

Hey All I am trying to recreate something I saw in an instructable a while back I can't figure out how to do it. They used Maya.

So I create the basic shape( the left one) and used the *Boolean Modifier* difference and the result is on the right. There is a sphere on the inside the design and the design is extruded inward.

How can I get this fixed? Thanks.

Comment: From a UV sphere, in edit mode, select all and: alt+p (to poke), alt+j (tri to quad) then alt+E (to extrude) and select 'individual faces' for the extrusion.

Comment: First thanks for the help, that got me alot closer but not all the way. http://imgur.com/a/we3a3 check out the pic

Comment: I think you missed a step, have a look at the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an UV sphere, this can be done with 3 magic shortcuts:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to poke the faces
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to make quads from tris
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> then individual faces to extrude faces

[image]

Additionally, it can be useful to keep these new vertices in a vertex group:

[image]

because it will allow to retrieve them easily for an eventual future modification. For instance:

[image]

Comment: For Those wanting to do this and don't like the top rectangles select the lines creating them and hit X and then dissolve edges.

Answer (score 0):

And you can use this new object with a boolean modifier.

[image]